# Optaplanner assigning incorrect planning entity during planning

Tags: java, optaplanner, optaweb-employee-rostering, optaweb-vehicle-routing

I have a use case where I want to assign a salesperson to a list of appointments. Now, these salespeople have to travel from one point to another to reach the appointment location. I am using Optaplanner to schedule a list of salesperson to a bunch of appointments. I have a constraint defined:

```
Constraint repConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        // A sales-rep can accommodate at most one appointment at the same time.
        return constraintFactory
                // Select each pair of 2 different appointments ...
                .forEachUniquePair(Appointment.class,
                        Joiners.equal(Appointment::getRepUuid))
                .filter((appt1, appt2) ->{
                    if(appt1.getStartTime().before(appt2.getStartTime()) &&
                            appt1.getEndTime().before(appt2.getStartTime()) &&
                            appt1.getStartTime().before(appt2.getEndTime()) &&
                            appt1.getEndTime().before(appt2.getEndTime())) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                })
                // ... and penalize each pair with a hard weight.
                .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
                .asConstraint("SalesRep conflict");
    }
```

This constraint checks if a sales rep is assigned to at most one appointment at any instance
The constraint works fine but the planner assigns some random sales rep for appointments with no feasible solution.
This completely makes the final solution unusable. Our requirement is if the solution is not feasible(no sales rep can be assigned) then don't assign anybody to the appointment.

I looked into the documentation and changed the `SolverFactory` with the following configuration but still no progress

```
SolverFactory<RepRoutingSolution> solverFactory = SolverFactory.create(new SolverConfig()
                .withSolutionClass(RepRoutingSolution.class)
                .withEntityClasses(Appointment.class)
                .withConstraintProviderClass(RepSchedulerConstraintProvider.class)
                .withTerminationConfig(new TerminationConfig()
                        .withBestScoreFeasible(true)
                )
                // The solver runs only for 5 seconds on this small dataset.
                // It's recommended to run for at least 5 minutes ("5m") otherwise.
                .withTerminationSpentLimit(Duration.ofSeconds(5)));


        // Load the problem
        RepRoutingSolution problem = generateDemoData();

        // Solve the problem
        Solver<RepRoutingSolution> solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();
        RepRoutingSolution solution = solver.solve(problem);

        // Visualize the solution
        printRepVisits(solution);
```

Edit 1:
Newly added constraint to reward for successfully assigning sales rep. This reward based constraint fixed the issue in my case

```
Constraint repRewardForAppointment(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        
        return constraintFactory
                // Select each pair of 2 different appointments ...
                .forEachUniquePair(Appointment.class,
                        Joiners.equal(Appointment::getRepUuid))
                .filter((appt1, appt2) -> {
                    if (appt1.getStartTime().before(appt2.getStartTime()) &&
                            appt1.getEndTime().before(appt2.getStartTime()) &&
                            appt1.getStartTime().before(appt2.getEndTime()) &&
                            appt1.getEndTime().before(appt2.getEndTime())) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                })
                // ... and penalize each pair with a hard weight.
                .reward(HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_MEDIUM)
                .asConstraint("SalesRep reward for Appointments");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're likely looking for is called [overconstrained planning](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/repeated-planning/repeated-planning.html#overconstrainedPlanning). You'll need a `nullable` planning variable.

Comment: I have updated my Planning variable to `nullable = true` but now after running the code, the planner doesn't assign any sales rep to any of the appointments. The entire solution has empty sales rep

Comment: `@PlanningEntity
public class Appointment {
    @PlanningId
    public Long uuid;
    public Timestamp startTime;
    public Timestamp endTime;

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "salesRepsRange", nullable = true)
    public SalesRep rep;
    public String description;
    public String customerUuid;
    public Location position;`

Comment: `@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "salesRepsRange", nullable = true)
    public SalesRep rep;`

Comment: This means that OP could not find any better solution than the one where everything is unassigned. This typically happens because everytime OP tries to assign something, the score gets worse. The way to fix that is either to make sure the constraints don't have that effect, or to introduce coarser-grained moves that change enough entities at the same time so that the solver has a chance to overcome this defficiency in constraints. Typically, you'd penalize all unassigned entities by a decent penalty, so that the solver has to pay a price if it wants to leave an entity unassigned.

Comment: Added one more constraint which will reward one medium score for each correct sales rep assignment and I think because of this the score improved for solutions other than having no reps assigned to any appointment.

Comment: Updated the question with the new constraint.